# Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I'm getting this message in Visual Studio:

> Note: C++ does not support default-int

What's wrong with my C code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void remplire (int t[], int n);
void afficher (int t[], int n);

void main ()
{
    const long_tab = 2000;
    int t[long_tab];
    srand (time(NULL));
    remplire (t, long_tab);
    afficher (t, long_tab);
}

void remplire (int t[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        t[i] = rand (); 
    }
}

void afficher (int t[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d \t", t[i]);
        if (i % 10 == 0)
            printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C++ shows this error when you omit the identifier type.

```
const int variable1; //OK
const variable2; //Not OK
```

This is MSDN description of the error:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173696%28VS.80%29.aspx

Also, if you highlight the error in the output tab and press F1 - Visual Studio Help will show you a page explaining the error in more detail, similar to the link above.

Comment: Implicit int has been removed in C99 and it isn't part of C++98 too.

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav is the C99 and C++98 std you are talking about, or it is just the implication by the Visual Studio. i.e means the other C/C++ IDE like eclipse will work fine for implicit int declarations.

Answer (score 1):

`const long_tab = 2000` should be `const int long_tab = 2000`. You may have other problems too, but I can't easily read your code because it got badly reformatted by SO.

Comment: could you pleas tell me where are the other mistakes

Comment: Now that Juliet reformatted your code, I don't see anything else wrong *related to that compiler error*.